# How Cube Camera updates its renderTarget according to eye

Tags: 3d, three.js

I am exploring some 3js samples and came across : http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Reflection.html which demoes reflections by a cube using  three js cube camera.

Context : The cube camera is still at one place and no code in update/render updates its orientation which means that the 6 cameras within are pointing at the same target as initially set.

Question : Why is then the reflection on cube and sphere updated as I move the main camera ? If the cameras are still pointing at the same target, same image should be generated for all eye/main camera positions. Does cube camera also considers eye direction while creating the image ?

Cant see anything referring the main camera here : http://threejsdoc.appspot.com/doc/three.js/src.source/extras/cameras/CubeCamera.js.html

Comment: Yes, the shader considers the angle of viewing, and the angle of the "reflective" surface, to decide what to show at each pixel on it...

Comment: Yes it seems so, but cant figure out at which stage that comes into picture. do you know which file contains the shader code ?